# changing icon of navigation drawer items

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, navigation-drawer, android-menu

When I changing icon in navigation drawer items by using (drawable > image asset > 'Action bar and tab icon') or (copy + past ) in drawable folder, in app menu icon shows the 'Theme color' witch was selected form " image asset > 'Action bar and tab icon' > Theme ".
I tried to all the three theme but main icon can not be shown
Here the [apps screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzsFJ.jpg) and activity_main_drawer.xml file and [xml file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFPQR.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_us"
        android:icon="@drawable/eee"
        android:title="US" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_world" android:icon="@drawable/bbb"
        android:title="World" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_tech" android:icon="@drawable/f_g_h"
        android:title="Tech" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_sports" android:icon="@drawable/f_g_h"
        android:title="Sports" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_worl" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        android:title="World" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_tec" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        android:title="Tech" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_sport" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        android:title="Sports" />


</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_star"
            android:title="About us" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_send" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Contact us" />


    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Do you have '@drawable/eee' (eee) file inside your drawable folder?

Comment: I think the issue is with drawables you are passing. Check whether you have 'eee','bbb','f_g_h','f_g_h' file inside any of drawable folders.

Comment: Thanks for answering. yes i have eee.png file in all drawable folder

Comment: ok. Check whether you are able to display 'eee' drawable in a activity using ImageView.

Comment: thanks. can you give me proper resource link how to add menu icon by using ImageView ?

Comment: No I didnt ask to add menu icon using imageview. Create a new blank activity and then insert imageview in layout and set 'eee' drawable. Run the activity on device and see if the drwable is visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Please have a look like this.